# Output formatting on OpenCV Python Face Recognition program

Tags: python, opencv, output-formatting

I am currently working on a face recognition project. My face recognition system shows recognized face ID in a white square box like below:

[image: My output]

But I want to format the output like below:

[image]

Output is formatted by using the following line:

```
cv2.cv.PutText(cv2.cv.fromarray(im),str(Id), (x,y+h),font, (255,255,255)
```

Comment: What's your question? Which part is unclear? [Drawing](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html) text at a different origin? [Drawing](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html) a filled in rectangle? [Blend two images](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/adding_images/adding_images.html) to achieve the transparent effect?

Comment: I want to know the exact method of text appearance like the second image. In the first image, it just only a white text nameplate. But I want to change it like the second image; a yellow blurred line and text overlayer over it.

Comment: Which method did you use for train your model ?